# How to edit the objects in FileMakerPro

Tags: filemaker

I have one doubt in filemaker pro. In my project I have one layout with a button(Lets say layout1). If I click on the button, it is navigating to next page(Lets say layout2). If I go to layout mode in this page(layout2), it is showing the layout mode of previous page(layout1). I checked the button setup in this page(layout1). It is calling some script(Lets say script1). In the script(script1) it is calling some object using "go to object[object name:nameoftheobject]". I want to make some changes in layout2. Is there any way to find this layout or suggest some ideas to edit the object 'nameoftheobject'?

Comment: You need to add your version of FileMaker Pro to get a better, less generic answer.

Comment: Filemakerpro 11Advanced

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not change the layout, instead the interface is re-drawn by going to an object covering a whole layout. It could be a hidden tab control, popover or slide control. Duplicate layout and try to select all and apply a visible border.

Comment: Hey hi am new to filemaker pro.. Could you please be bit clear?? After clicking on layout mode in layout2 it is moving to layout1 layout mode... I saw the button setup in the layout1. They have used Perform script with one script name. I have checked the script too. In the script there is only one line... Go to object[object name: bysourcename]... do you have any idea on this... Please help me out

Comment: I can see you are in FileMaker Pro 11, so it is a hidden Tab control. FileMaker does not change layout whey you go from one mode to another. To confirm, just look at the layout name in the top left corner in browse and layout name, it should be the same.

Comment: both having same name.

Comment: Which means the layout does not change. It is an old trick to make it look like you've changed layout when you haven't. Look for a tab control covering the whole layout whith the transparent background and border set to 0.

Comment: Thanks Nicolai ... Will check and let u know... so if i want add anything in the layout2, what should i do???

Comment: You need to make borders visible on the tab control and change to a different tab, where the objects are that  you can see after you click the button. Sometimes a developer will make the tabs very small, e.g. by using a very small font, or setting fixed size to 0. You might need temporarily change this parameters to change to the correct tab

Comment: Since am new to filemaker pro am not gettting you clearly...are you in skype? Please guide me in this.. am stuck in one small enhancement..

Comment: Gopinath, you can contact me directly on the email address in my profile. I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks Nicolai... Actually now i understood something. I will tel u clearly now.. Actually we are having one layout(lets say layout1). In this layout, there are two buttons. One button is calling one object and another button calling another object. Basically these two objects are present in the same layout(layout1) and they are in hidden state. When the user clicks on any of the button, the contents in the layout are going to hidden state and the corresponding objects are become visible.

Comment: Accidently without knowing this, we deleted the some of the textbox, label in the object. Plz help me to add the stuffs in the objects. And they should be hidden state, should only be visible after clicking the button in the layout.

Comment: This is the method how they are calling the objects from the layout. In layout button->right click:button setup->perform script(somename).
 In the script they are calling object using the below syntax
 Go to object[Object Name: "ISBN"]. So how to find the ISBN object and how to add the content like text box and label into ISBN object...

Comment: Gopinath, the format of the stackoverflow is not the best to resolve your problem, you would be much better off using one of the FileMaker forums. I will be happy to help, but you need to communicate to me directly. Click on my name and look at my profile. use the email from my profile to get in touch directly.